# Trying to run python program on all files in directory NEED TO SCAN AND USE EACH FILE NAME

Tags: python, directory, filenames

I wrote a very basic program to remove quotation marks from a text file. I have about 50 files I need to run and would rather run the program for all text files in a directory...

The **big** issue I am having is that I need the files to be read one at a time, and once the `"` are stripped, all the contents of the file outputted to a new file  which uses the name of the input file.

For example:

As I have it now, the program takes the input file name as an argument, and creates the output file name as the `infile name + _output.txt`. How do I make it so it processes all the text files in a directory but names the files how I want it to?

My program:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) <2:
    print "Usage: python %s requires input file" % (sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit()

infile = sys.argv[1]
outfile = infile.split(".")[0] + "_output.txt"

INFH = open(infile)
OFH = open(outfile, "w")

print "Output File = %s" % (outfile)

for line in INFH:
    line=line.strip('\n').replace('\"','')

    print >> OFH, line
INFH.close()
```

Comment: Strange indentation...

Comment: I'ts from trying to cooperate with stack overflow's code block system for asking questions

Comment: Use `os.listdir(path)` and `os.path.isfile(path)` for this.

Comment: I understand using os.listdir, but how does os.path.isfile help?

Comment: `os.listdir(path)` returns files **and** folders in a directory. Use `os.path.isfile(path)` to make shure it's a file.

Comment: That doesn't solve my issue....I know the file names I need and I also don't care to check that it is a file. I just need to pull the file name from each txt file and use it to make my output file name...

Comment: I've written an answer. BTW, please accept the edit I made to your code...

Comment: Oh, and what version of Python are you using? I think `print >> fileobj, "string"` isn't up-to-date Python code, should open file in append mode and the `fileobj.write("string")`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
import sys, os

if len(sys.argv) < 2 and not os.path.isdir(sys.argv[1]):
    print("Usage: python {} directory".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit()

for entry in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
    if os.path.isfile(entry):
        infile = entry
        outfile = infile.split(".")[0] + "_output.txt"

        INFH = open(infile)
        OFH = open(outfile, "a")

        print("Output File = {}".format(outfile))

        for line in INFH:
            line = line.strip('\n').replace('\"','')
            OFH.write(line)

        INFH.close()
```

Just add an directory instead of an file as argument.

Comment: This returns an IndexError:list index out of range

Comment: Hmm, do you use sth. like `python yourfile.py ./dir/`?

Comment: @cobaltchaos I've made some changes to the code, please try again. Works for me under Windows 10 and Python 3.4.4